# Can I cross compile with gcc for an old version of a Linux distro on my Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I have some old hardware with an old version of say SuSE linux running on it. Now I have this fancy development machine running Ubuntu 9.10. Some of the tools I use to compile my C app (written in Python 2.6.x) are not available on the old SuSe box. So... is it possible to compile for that old machine on my dev box?

I have the following steps in mind, but would like to cross-check before venturing off into this quest:
1. Find out which static/shared libs my app needs and find/build target version of them
2. Also find the corresponding header files
3. Feed the correct flags to gcc to use the target headers and libraries
4. Feed the correct flags to gcc to use the correct architecture (i386/i686), or do I need a cross-compilation toolchain.
5. Compile, upload and enjoy ;-)

I regularly use avr-gcc and cc65, both are cross compiling. I know that you set up a coss compiler for developing something like a gumstix, so it should be possible to do the same for old/other Linux distros, not?

C

Comment: Yes, and headers and libraries will be the biggest pain (if they are a pain).  A new version of gcc may assume that the functionality from a certain version of glibc is present.  There are ways around this, and if you're using avr-gcc you're probably going to be able to get this going with out too much trouble.  You may need cross versions of some binutils if you are moving between x86-64 and x86-32.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would approach this is grab your `oldmachine:/usr/lib` and `oldmachine:/usr/include` so you have e.g. `newmachine:/oldmachinecompiler/usr/{lib|include}`  then build a cross compiler setting `--sysroot` to `newmachine:/oldmachinecompiler/`

This is really the only way to ensure that any library requirements (including libc) in your program are compatible with `oldmachine`.