# ImageMagick 100% static build for Linux

Tags: makefile, compilation, imagemagick, configure

I'm working with legacy system and I need to statically build ImageMagick (6.9 and/or 7.x), because the one in use is very old and has some bugs fixed by more recent versions (and I need these fixes).

I've checked plenty of resources, all coming with different solutions and they got me confused. I have no idea how to work with make and configure and thus I really need something definitive.

For current version I only have executables (ldd says "not a dynamic executable" for each one of them) and etc directory containing some XML configuration (I assume) files.

I need the same thing, just with more recent ImageMagick version.

## UPDATE

Just wanted to say that when I use this command to configure it:
`LDFLAGS="-static" ./configure --without-modules --enable-static --enable-delegate-build --disable-shared`

I end up with

```
ldd convert
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc71518000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f88f254f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f88f2246000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f88f202f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f88f1e12000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f88f1a48000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f88f1843000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559c6e584000)
```

Which obviously doesn't work for me, I'd like the whole thing to be statically linked.

Comment: Are you compiling on the old system? The output of `ldd` looks right, as core system libraries will be required to allocate memory, manage threads, & etc.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803292/438117)

Comment: I'm compiling on CentOS 7 for CentOS 7. I can't have any libraries linked dynamically, I need all executables to be 100% static.